# How To Store Data In Python dictionary

Tags: python

I have developed a script where i am reading 100k lines in file.
I need to fetch data from 50 000 to 100 000 based on this it will search for availability in 1 to 50k lines and as to fetch corresponding data from the line.

in order to do this i am opening text file in for loop for searching data
can you help how to store data in python dictionary so that script doesn't
require to process big text file multiple times and eventually reduce time

Comment: what kind of data is present in the txt file? Rows and columns? And how is it seperated?

Comment: If you do `lst = open('file.txt').readlines()`, then `lst` will be a list in memory that you can process as many times as you want.

Comment: *NODE
101, 0., 0., 0.
102, 1., 0., 0.
103, 2., 0., 0.
104, 0.5, 0.866, 0.
105, 1.5, 0.866, 0.                                                                                             
 *ELEMENT, TYPE=T2D2, ELSET=FRAME
11, 101,102
12, 102,103
13, 101,104
14, 102,104
15, 102,105
16, 103,105
17, 104,105                 like above from row 8 to 14  its gets corresponding number 15 it has 102,103 in corresponding columns it has to search  for 102 in 1 to 6 rows then it has to fetch corresponding column values

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? You mention not to read the file multiple times which means u know how to read the file. Why not read the entire file at first attemp then ? Is the file too large to be loaded in memory ? You have mentioned the problem, but what have u done to solve it ? how are u reading the file now ?

Comment: Yes Can you help me to how  store data the entire data of file as similar format how data is there in file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file consists of rows and columns and each record is seperated by a comma. Rather than saving it to dictionary, it would be better if the records are saved to a pandas dataframe. You could do something like,

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', sep=',')
print(data.head())
```

If you want to save this dataframe to a csv format you can do so by using to_csv() method of pandas.

Comment: yes i tried with this but the column index is omitting so data say top 10 lines have  4 columns  and 10-20 lines have 9 columns with different spacing when compared to 0-10lines...data = pd.read_fwf('filename.txt', sep=',')

Comment: could you show exactly what is being printed on your terminal?